# In Stylus, How to convert a percentage to integer?

Tags: casting, integer, percentage, stylus

There is the `percentage` function which converts a number to a percentage, but there is no `number` (or `integer`) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code `unit(10%, number)` you get: `10number`. You have to replace the unit for an empty string: `unit(10%, '') => 10`

If you want the reverse of percentage: `percentage(.1) => 10%` you have to divide by 100: `(unit(10%, '')/100) => 0.1`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `unit` function:

```
unit(10%, number) // 10
```